# Sharepoint WSS3 Frontend Server Config

Tags: sharepoint, raid

Any suggestions of the hardware config for a single frontend WSS3 server?  The database is on another server so it will just be running Sharepoint. Raid Config? RAM? Will start as Win2k3 64bit.

Thanks

Comment: @Pat: this is a really open ended question. Any idea about possible usage? (Number of Users? Sites? Documents?, etc.)

Comment: At this point only about 4-6 sites with ~100 users. One site will be for Solid Edge (engineering app) document library. I often setup a server with mirrored root and Raid 5 data but am wondering if that is necessary with the Sharepoint data been held on the DB server?

Answer (score 0):

Raid Config
1. Raid1 OS
2. Raid2 ISS, Sharepoint, Website

Hard to say for memory and CPU, consider usage budget lifespan etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems pretty minimal, so I would say you can get away with pretty minimal requirements.

- At least 4gb ram
- OS/SharePoint install on local disk
- SharePoint "data"/IIS websites maybe on RAID 5 (or better RAID 10) but not necessarily. If you do move things out to a faster RAID system it would help to make sure your pagefile goes there too.

Now, if you plan on implementing Search Server Express on top of WSS, I would say you need to up the ram to 8gb and put the search indexes out on some fast RAID 10.

Here is the documentation for WSS performance planning:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288633.aspx

And here is the link for Search Server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc979155.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was looking at the bare min of just two mirrored drives seeing as the data is on the sql box but after reading your reply I am guessing I would have some bottle neck issues with the iis sites and page file?  Am I correct in thinking there isn't much data stored locally as far as Sharepoint is concerned?

Comment: I agree - the RAID5/10 for SharePoint website info isn't a deal breaker, especially at your usage level.